# Excel Formula SUMIFS on date and time using date from given cell

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

Excel 2016 (office 365, current version)

I have a formula that works, but is manually intensive (i.e. manually edit the date in two places for each formula, and I have to do this for an entire quarter's worth of data):

- =SUMIFS('Raw'!$E:$E,'Raw'!$A:$A,">=3/30/2017 0:00",'Raw'!$A:$A,"<=3/30/2017 23:00")
- yields: 35.69658611 (Correct, actual sample data below)

I would like to be able to take the date value for the local sheet column M (list of dates for the month) and plug that date directly into the formula so I can copy paste the formula to calculate the rest of the month.

What I have returns a value of zero:

- =SUMIFS('Raw'!$E:$E,'Raw'!$A:$A,">="&M3 &" 0:00",'Raw'!$A:$A,"<="&M3 &" 23:00")

DataTable:  Raw

Date/Time value:  'Raw' column A

Data to sum:  'Raw' Column E

Both formulas are based on hint from https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/601474-sumifs-date-range-criteria.html

Sample data:

```
DateTime        kW
3/30/17 23:00   0
3/30/17 22:00   0
3/30/17 21:00   0
3/30/17 20:00   0
3/30/17 19:00   0.004455278
3/30/17 18:00   0.5370675
3/30/17 17:00   2.303020833
3/30/17 16:00   4.122186389
3/30/17 15:00   5.415064722
3/30/17 14:00   6.190184167
3/30/17 13:00   3.621349167
3/30/17 12:00   3.292333056
3/30/17 11:00   4.470871944
3/30/17 10:00   2.407315556
3/30/17 9:00    2.269564167
3/30/17 8:00    1.033854722
3/30/17 7:00    0.029317778
3/30/17 6:00    0
3/30/17 5:00    0.000000556
3/30/17 4:00    0
3/30/17 3:00    0
3/30/17 2:00    0
3/30/17 1:00    0.000000278
3/30/17 0:00    0
```

Comment: What, exactly, did you put in `M3` and how is it formatted?

Comment: M3 is "3/30/2017" (without the Quotation marks)

Comment: Quick test - try just `3/30/17`

Comment: as soon as I hit enter, excel reformats it to 3/30/2017 and the result is still 0

Comment: note:  I didn't catch it before, but the sample data is actually a 4 digit year (i.e. 3/30/2017 23:00), not a 2 digit year, don't know how/why it reformatted when I copied it out earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remember how the date format work in Excel.
Every day since 1900/01/00 (arbitrary chosen date) are indexed.
So in short, when you type 2017/03/30 in cell M3 excel really only read "42824".

```
=SUMIFS('Raw'!$E:$E,'Raw'!$A:$A,">="&$M3 &" 0:00",'Raw'!$A:$A,"<="&$M3 &" 23:00")
```

Only change required is that you must save date in Text format (i.e, prepend an apostrophe (') to the date, thereby not allowing excel to auto-format as Date).

Comment: I have a feeling that's involved in the core of my problem, I just don't know how to fix... maybe force conversion of the data in the column to "text" only?

Comment: THIS!!!!  Must save date in Text format, not allow excel to auto select and reformat as Date.

Thanks @MrDogme, that did the trick

Comment: A par of what I said is false, sorry SO.  Surprisingly excel does translate 3/30/2017 properly. It only become a problem while breaking the expression and refering to some cells. Humm I'm out of ideas, if I manage to find it Ill let you know.

Comment: oh Good. Glad I could help!

Comment: MrDogme, Please consider editing your answer; correcting what you mentioned in your comments and also include @Gavin142 's answer in your post since your post has been accepted (reference to it as he/she referenced to you in the answer below). Your answer is not useful as how it looks like right now. By the way, congrats on comment privilege.

Answer (score 0):

The final working formula was almost exactly the same as my second one, the only change really was the added $ to lock in the column on the textual concatenation:

```
=SUMIFS('Raw'!$E:$E,'Raw'!$A:$A,">="&$M3 &" 0:00",'Raw'!$A:$A,"<="&$M3 &" 23:00")
```

Only change required is that you Must save date in Text format (i.e, prepend an apostrophe (') to the date, thereby not allowing excel to auto-format as Date)

Special thanks to @MrDogme for the trigger that helped me fix the problem.